# How to connect Azure MLStudio with Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ml-studio

I am trying to connect MLStudio with Snowflake, however I see there is no connector for snowflake. How can I connect. I want to use snowflake directly and don't want to use Azure blobs or ADL to run ML algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Azure [ML service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-service/), you can run a generic Python 3 code. you can use the [`Snowflake python connector`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector.html)

With Azure ML Studio, there's no built-in support for SnowFlake